# Changing foreign key to ON DELETE CASCADE with least amount of impact

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.5, online-operations

I have an existing foreign key that has `ON DELETE NO ACTION` defined. I need to change this foreign key to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I can do this within a transaction:

```sql
begin;
alter table posts drop constraint posts_blog_id_fkey;
alter table posts add constraint posts_blog_id_fkey foreign key (blog_id) references blogs (id) on update no action on delete cascade;
commit;
```

The problem is that the `posts` table is large (4 million rows) which means that validating the foreign key can take a non-trivial amount of time (I've tested this with a copy of the database). Dropping/adding the foreign key [acquires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html#AEN72289) on `posts`. So, adding the foreign key blocks *all* access to the `posts` table for a decent amount of time because the lock is held while constraint validation occurs. I need to perform an online migration (I don't have a dedicated downtime window).

I know that I can perform **2 transactions** to help with the check taking a long time:

```sql
begin;
alter table posts drop constraint posts_blog_id_fkey;
alter table posts add constraint posts_blog_id_fkey foreign key (blog_id) references blogs (id) on update no action on delete cascade not valid;
commit;

begin;
alter table posts validate constraint posts;
commit;
```

The advantage of this approach is that the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock is held for a very short time for dropping/adding the constraint and then for validating the constraint only [a `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` on `posts` and `ROW SHARE` lock on `blogs`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html) since I'm on Postgres 9.5.

Are there downsides to this? I know that adding `NOT VALID` to the constraints means that *existing* data is not validated, but any rows inserted/updated before the `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` *will* be checked. Because the foreign key is dropped/added in the same transaction, is there any possibility of creating inconsistent data?

Comment: see if my post gets you anywhere with clearing up the NOT VALID situation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The docs say this about [`NOT VALID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html)

> ```
> ADD table_constraint [ NOT VALID ]
> ```
>
> This form adds a new constraint to a table using the same syntax as `CREATE TABLE`, **plus the option `NOT VALID`, which is currently only allowed for foreign key and CHECK constraints. If the constraint is marked `NOT VALID`, the potentially-lengthy initial check to verify that all rows in the table satisfy the constraint is skipped. The constraint will still be enforced against subsequent inserts or updates (that is, they'll fail unless there is a matching row in the referenced table, in the case of foreign keys; and they'll fail unless the new row matches the specified check constraints). But the database will not assume that the constraint holds for all rows in the table, until it is validated by using the `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` option.**

Your concern,

> I know that adding `NOT VALID` to the constraints means that existing data is not validated, but any rows inserted/updated before the `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` will be checked.

They'll only be checked during validation *AFTER* you tell it to validate, so you can delay that until you have scheduled downtime.

> Because the foreign key is dropped/added in the same transaction, is there any possibility of creating inconsistent data?

No, because the second you add the `NOT VALID` it applies to all rows inserted *AFTER* the statement as if they were always there. VALIDATION is for the rejection of creating an `FOREIGN KEY` when the referenced rows do not exist. It has *nothing* to do with cascading, observe

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT 1 AS a;

CREATE TABLE bar
AS
  SELECT a
  FROM ( VALUES (1),(2) )
    AS t(a);

ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (a);

ALTER TABLE bar
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (a)
  REFERENCES foo
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  NOT VALID;

DELETE FROM foo;


TABLE foo;
 a 
---
(0 rows)

test=# TABLE bar;
 a 
---
 2
(1 row)
```

At this point you can see

1. the deletion from `bar` cascaded to `bar`
2. the lack of validation on bar means it still has a row that is *invalid*

The constraint still can't be validated (as shown below), but for the purposes of cascaded deletion all things are good.

```
ALTER TABLE bar VALIDATE CONSTRAINT bar_a_fkey  ;
ERROR:  insert or update on table "bar" violates foreign key constraint "bar_a_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (a)=(2) is not present in table "foo".
```

Btw you can write this

```
begin;
alter table posts drop constraint posts_blog_id_fkey;
alter table posts add constraint posts_blog_id_fkey foreign key (blog_id) references blogs (id) on update no action on delete cascade not valid;
commit;
```

Like this

```
alter table posts
  drop constraint posts_blog_id_fkey,
  add constraint posts_blog_id_fkey
    foreign key (blog_id)
    references blogs (id)
    on update no action
    on delete cascade
    not valid;
```

You don't have to wrap it in a txn. You also don't have to wrap any single statement in a txn -- PostgreSQL isn't MySQL. Everything is already transactional.

Comment: Thanks. I understood everything from the documentation about `NOT VALID`, I just wanted to clarify this specific situation when changing `ON DELETE NO ACTION` to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.